# What causes multiple Mails when using Cron with Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, cron, rsync, msmtp

I've made a little bash script to backup my nextcloud files including my database from my ubuntu 18.04 server. I want the backup to be executed every day. When the job is done I want to reseive **one mail** if the job was done (additional if it was sucessful or not). With the current script I reseive **almost 20 mails** and I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

My cronjob looks like this:

```
* 17 * * * "/root/backup/"backup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

My bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

LOG="/user/backup/backup.log"

exec > >(tee -i ${LOG})

exec 2>&1

cd /var/www/nextcloud

sudo -u www-data php occ maintenance:mode --on

mysqldump --single-transaction -h localhost -u db_user --password='PASSWORD' nextcloud_db > /BACKUP/DB/NextcloudDB_`date +"%Y%m%d"`.sql

cd /BACKUP/DB
ls -t | tail -n +4 | xargs -r rm --


rsync -avx --delete /var/www/nextcloud/ /BACKUP/nextcloud_install/
rsync -avx --delete --exclude 'backup' /var/nextcloud_data/ /BACKUP/nextcloud_data/

cd /var/www/nextcloud
sudo -u www-data php occ maintenance:mode --off

echo "###### Finished backup on $(date) ######"


mail -s "BACKUP" name@domain.com < ${LOG}
```

Comment: Cron string should be `0 17 * * *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure about the CRON string? For me this means "At every minute past hour 17".

Should be more like `0 17 * * *`, right?

Comment: I will try that out. Thank you very much.
Any idea how to get information about the rsync status so that I can receive a mail that indicates if the job was successful or not?

Comment: I guess rsync will also exit with a proper status code on error/success which you can check with `$?` (0 = success, 1 = error). This should be useful.

Comment: I will give it a try. and post it here ;-)